# Fill combobox with XML data

Tags: c#, xml, combobox, uwp

I want to get data from a XML file (https://xml.buienradar.nl/) and fill a combobox with that data. I want each regio from `<weerstation regio=>`
 to be shown in the combobox.

I could not find anything working for me in UWP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way is to use `XElement` to load XML and then query over it.

First you need `ComboBox` in XAML page:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="Stations" />
```

Add new event handler for `Loaded` event and in code behind use this code to load XML and fill ComboBox:

```
        private void MainPage_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var requestUri = new Uri("https://xml.buienradar.nl/");

            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var httpResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync(requestUri);
            httpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            var httpResponseStream = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

            var root = XElement.Load(httpResponseStream);
            var stations =
                from element in root.Descendants("weerstation")
                select element;

            foreach (var station in stations)
            {
                Stations.Items?.Add(station.Attribute("id")?.Value);
            }
        }
```

[image: UWPApp]

Here is [link to source where I get idea](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/how-to-find-all-nodes-in-a-namespace).
And also [link where you'll find documentation how to do simple HTTP GET request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/httpclient).

Comment: I am getting an error: **Cannot open 'https://xml.buienradar.nl/'. The Uri parameter must be a file system relative or absolute path.'**

Comment: Sorry, I just updated mu answer how to do GET request.

Comment: Thanks, this did it for me! Now I need to retrieve the data from the selected station and fill a GridView with that data, any chance you could help with that?

Comment: That is pretty common task, but still not easy to accomplish. [Here's some hint](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5f9698d1-c1bc-4195-806e-7e575f348734/uwpdatagrid-alternative-for-uwp?forum=wpdevelop). Anyway, there's lot of documentation and examples for UWP. Don't be afraid to ask your preferred search engine ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [LinqToXML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-xml-overview) to read the data and then set that as the ItemSource.

Comment: _in purchaseOrder_  is from a file, how can I use the webservice provided?

Comment: It doesn't matter where the XML comes from - just read it into an in-memory object and set the ItemSource of the ComboBox.  If you use some kind of binding, you could potentially just have the combo box pointing at a model field, and simply populate that field, instantly relfecting the new state to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can start of with the following snippet (see in action [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VEmBXA)):

```
var xml = XDocument.Load("https://xml.buienradar.nl/");
var weerstationList = xml.Descendants("weerstation");
var weerstations = weerstationList.Select(w => new Item()
    {
        Id = w.Attribute("id").Value,
        Name = w.Descendants("stationnaam").First().Value
    });
```

and the following helper class:

```
public class Item
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

You can then set the list of items `weerstations` as your `ItemSource` of the combo-box.